# Using TikZ, how can I bend the edge between two nodes in a tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I tried setting `edge from parent/.style={draw, bend left=60}`, but the line remains straight. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={
                draw,
                circle,
        },
        edge from parent/.style={
                draw,
                bend left=25,
        },
]
\node {}
        child {node {}}
        child {node {}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mwe](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @Claudio Added it now.

Comment: Sorry to insist but that's not a MWE. It should start with `\documentclass{}` and up to `\end{document}` with necessary libraries etc. The common problem for us is to guess if any library is needed or not.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that I should add the rest too (I thought that was part of being minimal). Here it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of

```
    edge from parent/.style={
            draw,
            bend left=25,
    },
```

I put

```
    edge from parent path={
            (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) edge [bend left=25]  (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
    },
```

and it worked!

Comment: The explanation is that `bend left` only makes sense in a `to` or `edge` path construction.  The default `edge from parent path` is drawn with just a line-to: `--`.

Comment: (Well done for figuring it out yourself, by the way)